# Will structs and value types (like C#'s) be included in Java 7?

Tags: c#, java, struct, value-type, java-7

Will structs and value types (like C#'s) be included in Java 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I've seen in any proposals - and I'm pretty sure we'd have heard about it by now.

Note that this would be a very significant JVM change, rather than just a language change as many of the existing proposals are.

Answer (score 5):

Here is John Rose's (an Oracle JVM developer) blog post about this proposal.  It has been around for a while, but not as an official JSR.  It seems unlikely to happen even in java 9.

http://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/tuples_in_the_vm

Comment: Java Value Types are part of Project Valhalla which is planned for Java 10.

Answer (score 4):

As posted elsewhere, from JDK architect John Rose

http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html

This is part of Project Valhalla (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) and is planned for Java 10.

Comment: If the Framework can support arrays of value types, is it better for boxed value type `T` to have the members of `T`, or for it to have a member `value` of type `T`?  Although .NET takes the former approach, I think in many ways the latter would be cleaner (I dislike autoboxing, and dislike auto-unboxing even more).

Answer (score 0):

It's not listed among the features expected according to the [Java Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_7#Java_SE_7.0).  It would also require a very large (and almost certainly breaking) change in the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

that's actually not the best thing from c# which you can borrow, I think that stuff like

```
var x = 1;
list.Select(o => o.Something = true) lambda expressions
```

and some stuff from as or javascript like:

```
o = new Object();
o.MyNewProp = 5
o.Do = new Function(){}
```

would be much better

Comment: please no!.... lambda expressions are just syntactic sugar for some form of function object. saving typing at the expense of adding complexity to the Java language syntax is a net loss IMO. the Javascript dynamic stuff is nice, but kills performance because it cannot be statically compiled - so it belongs on a dynamic language for the JVM (e.g. Groovy, Clojure, JRuby), not Java itself